# java integer array size confusion

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management

I have this code

`int[] i = new int[127*1024];`

is working

`int[] i = new int[128*1024];`

is throwing

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at memory.main(memory.java:123)`

running this using the following command in a 64 bit windows machine, jdk 1.8
`java -Xms1M -Xmx1M memory`

As per my understanding, java int is of 4 bytes(32 bit) and int[] array is an object.
In the above case its failing if the size is 131.072 bytes(128 * 1024) with 1mb of heap space
Can anyone help in explaining why its going out of memory?

Comment: I'm sorry, did you assume nothing else in the heap was taking up any space?  Say, all the other infrastructure for a Java VM?

Comment: And the size is 128*1024*4 bytes (+a few bytes of overhead), so 4 times as much as you said.

Comment: You're using at least 128*1024*4=524288 bytes for this array, leaving less than 1/2Mb for the rest of Java. Never seen it run that small in 20 years.

Comment: this counts to 4 * 128 * 1024 ~512 bytes... u mean additional bytes overhead also accounts to 512 bytes to fill 1 mb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Space for every element of the array is allocated on array creation.
All elements are initialized to `0`.

`int` values are `4` bytes, so this array causes `128 * 1024 * 4` bytes to be allocated, which is 0.5 Mb.

Your array is *not* the only object on the heap at that line of code, which is why your JVM explodes, even though you gave it 1 Mb of memory.

You need to give more memory to your JVM to avoid this error.

Comment: @VinodKrishnan there's not much more to explain. Try this: All the space ever needed by the array is allocated when it's created. Assigning values to array elements uses zero memory - the place to hold the value has already been allocated.